# magento : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, url, css

when i press f12 and see console i am getting above error

this is the site :

i want to know what actually happening.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is trying to load the Javascript file yourjs.js from the URL:

```
http://cdn.SOMEURL.com/js/yourjs.js
```

But the browser cannot find the file at that URL.

The browser is trying to load the file due to line 67 of `http://SOMEURL.com/`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.SOMEURL.com/js/yourjs.js"></script>
```

It is possible that the file `yourjs.js` never existed and that it is just a placeholder left over from development.

Do you have the file yourjs.js? Do you know which part of your theme is trying to load it? (hint: do a text search in files on your Magento code seeking yourjs.js).

If you have the file yourjs.js then you should upload that to your CDN in the folder `/js/` so that the URL will point to the file `http://cdn.SOMEURL.com/js/yourjs.js`.

**If you don't have that file**, it might be simplest to create an empty file, name it yourjs.js and upload it your CDN anyway.

That way the link will no longer be broken and you will save hours trying to figure out which part of Magento is trying to load it (hint: `app/design/frontend/themename/default/layout/layout.xml`).

The file doesn't seem to be needed by the web page because there are no other JavaScript errors and the page looks like it is fully functional.

The website http://demo2.ANOTHERURL.com/ does not fetch the file yourjs.js. I do think that it is a non-file and just a placeholder from some development example. So just upload an empty file to your CDN in its place.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's a problem with cdn, it's happening because we did cdn for our site, so whatever we are doing it's taking some time to display in frontend.

please remove site name and link from your answer.....

Comment: I removed the URL references. I note that you haven't combined all your javascript and CSS into one file; that will help page load speed a little bit - you now have a lot of requests to the CDN but the browser will only open 6 requests at a time. **But** your page load speed is dominated by your server response time ('time to first byte') of ~1 second. You should spend some time looking into why that is. Check that the Magento caches are on and that the Magento compiler is enabled. I would expect you to be able to get under 0.5 seconds and maybe even under 0.25 seconds for 'time to first byte'

Comment: thanks a lot for your support, is i have to use any extension for combining js and css files? or can i use some options under cache management?

Comment: @Malachy I am getting error like https://snag.gy/YLwvBm.jpg, backend screenshot: https://snag.gy/I1mLRz.jpg how can i solve this error..